# How can the behavior of my .msi on Windows Vista and Seven be so weird?

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-installer, windows-vista, installshield

---

I have a .msi created with InstallShield that i'm trying to work correctly in a per user installation for Windows Vista and Seven.

I'm virtualizing Vista and Seven with virtuabox, with 3 accounts each :

-Admin1 (default account)

-Admin2

-User1

**Whatever account i'm signed, it always install the software for Admin1, and the .msi always give me the choice between Permachine and peruser.**

i can give the value i want (through InstallShield) to Allusers parameter, it doesn't affect the behavior on Vista and Seven.

I'm desperatly trying to use Orca/windows installer logs/Winlogutl.exe
I don't know what to look for with these tools.

So My question is :
How can the behavior of my .msi on Windows Vista and Seven be so weird?
What can i look for to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the [`ALLUSERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559.aspx) property, as occasionally used before the UAC era to provide a "for all users or just me" option, was not well conceived and does not work well, especially in the post-UAC era. On Windows Vista, you can only choose one value for the setting on your .msi package that has it elevate or not; `ALLUSERS` does not change this. Since it always (or never) elevates, you can really only handle one of the two scenarios.

Windows 7 and Windows Installer 5 introduced the [`MSIINSTALLPERUSER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408007.aspx) property which can override the setting that causes the package to elevate. Thus the same package can either elevate and install for everyone, or can remain non-elevated and install for "just me". While versions of InstallShield since Windows 7 came out provide this configuration option, it will still not work on Windows Vista.

So unfortunately you cannot get the behavior it sounds like you desire on Windows Vista unless you offer two packages. Your single package will always (or never) elevate, and thus will always install for everyone or just the administrative account to which it elevates. For Windows 7 you should be able to use the `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` approach.

Comment: As far as i understood, in InstallShield's ALLUSERS=2 is set, and the user click just me, it sets MSIINSTALLPERUSER at 1 and should install the package for him, not the account it elevates. But that doesn't happen on Windows seven.

Comment: Don't merely check understandings; check a verbose log. Look for changes to and the final value of both properties, as well as the resulting changes to the directory properties, if any.